# Simulating a hand based on python conditions

Tags: python, animation, bones

I am trying to showcase a EMG signal simulator on a hand represented by an armature. Trying to simulate a hand prosthetic.
I have looked everywhere but couldn't find an answers to my question.

Let's say I have a simple array: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0 , 1]
The hand should close from a transition from 0->1, open from a transition from 1->0, remain closed on repeating 1s and remain open on repeating 0s.

The project is a bit more complicated but if knew that I would know how to do the rest.
Any pointers on how to control an armature via python and make it do different animations depending on a condition like the one described above?

https://youtu.be/nmP8iGaPbeI?list=PLCtC-wuFk2xmUf_pX_mPAw0tnJclVWHEk&t=206
Similar to how it's done in here.

Comment: The tricky part here is turning the list of numbers into something that can be read during an animation, however there are thankfully multiple ways to do this. You could try turning it into an audio signal and then baking that key frames, or you could simply have a program create the key frames from the list directly*

Comment: * The problem is I have never done the second one successfully, and I tried really hard once.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard
https://imgur.com/rHMETgf
Well can't it be done more simply? Like in here but instead of the prints there would be some command to rotate one of the bones on a axis?